# How to make a uniform random distribution but where result is revealed in steps?

Tags: algorithm

For example, let's say there is a array of items each equally likely to be chosen, and the output of this random function will tell which item to be chosen, but I want the function to be split into multiple steps so that along each step the list of potential items is narrowed in giving better insight on the result probabilities.

Here's a step by step example of how it might work:

Step 1: Every item is 1/1000 chance.

Step 2: Random subset of half the original set is removed, so each remaining item is 1/500 now.

Step 3: Repeat step 2 until narrowed down to a single item.

The requirements I'd like for the algorithm is < O(n) time complexity and at each step the distribution is still uniformly random.

---

Initially I though to have an algorithm which:

1. Start with variables `min` and `max` describing the current range of values left.
2. Shrink the range by generating random float number between [-1, 1] which is applied to the range to shrink it proportionally. If random number is negative then lower the max, otherwise raise the min. So 50% of the time it is shifting the min up, and shifting the max down, and the range is shrinking by a factor between [0,1].
3. Repeat 2. until range converges on a single number.

But I noticed this doesn't have a uniform distribution, and instead it is more common for the chosen result to be closer to starting min and max values. So to fix this I think one could add a preliminary step where the starting range is offset by another random value. But this would only fix in making the starting distribution uniformly random, and it still doesn't fit my requirement of making it uniformly random at every step.

The naive solution is to generate random numbers and remove those from the list until at each step, but that is a O(n) solution so I hope there is something better.

Comment: 1. Pick the winning number. 2. Shuffle the remaining losing numbers. 3. Display numbers, with winning number inserted at random.  4. After every display re-shuffle the remaining losing numbers. 5. Repeat from step 3 until only the winning number is left. 6. Display the winning number.

Comment: @rossum Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, why shuffle? Isn't the naive solution I outlined which is already O(n) better or no?

Comment: Also,  in case it's not clear I forgot to mention that the whole process should be done on demand so to speak. i.e. It's not that the number is chosen already and then we just need to reveal a sub-range to hint what it might be. The number is unknown to everybody until the pseudo-random number generator is run with the algorithm.

Comment: The shuffle is so that the chosen number is less obvious. It seems to me that a random placement would be easier than trying to keep all the numbers in order while still masking the winning number. YMMV

Comment: @rossum I appreciate the input but I don't understand where that insight is coming from.  There is no need to mask the winning number because it shouldn't be known until the process is completed. To clarify about my question: I want to know if there is a better method of randomly distilling down a set, than the naive method I posted initially. Was your comment with that understanding in mind?

Comment: I wanted to separate the winning number at the start, so the remainder of the set - the non-winners - could be treated as a single object with all the same properties. No need for extra code to pick the winner out from the losers every round. Hold it separately, and just re-insert it for display purposes only, keeping it separate in the back-end data.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to apply [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

If you randomly remove a portion `p` of the remaining possibilities, the remaining items have their probabilities multiplied by `1/(1-p)`.  So in your step 2, the probabilities change by an amount corresponding to how much the range changed.  And not by a fixed factor.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate the answer but it's not the one I'm looking for. I guess I should re-word the question to: is there a efficient way to remove a portion of the initial set randomly such that the resulting subset is not biased?

Comment: @Buretto Simply give each element an independent chance of `p` of being removed?

Comment: I want the runtime to be < O(n) though, so tackling the problem that way is going in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Buretto so this algorithm amounts to, generate two uniform random numbers in the interval, call them x and y. We split the interval at x, taking the half that contains y.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thank you for sharing. I tried testing this in JS to see how it compares to my idea (they seem very similar), and was surprised to see they had opposite effects. But I suspect it might be due to coding error on my part, not sure. [Here is my attempt at yours](https://jsfiddle.net/jz9301bo/2/), it doesn't work on the web for me but that is the code. It results in the first and last buckets having 1/2 the rest of the buckets. My other idea has the opposite where the middle buckets had 1/2 compared to the starting buckets.

Comment: @Buretto There are two issues. First, the first and last bins in your code are half-width due to round() -- try that histogram with a straightforward generator. Second, my description was good enough for floats but not ints; if you want to do ints, generate a random boundary x in [min+1, max) with whatever distribution you like (e.g., uniform), generate uniform y in [min, max), and then set max = x if y < x else min = x.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has some very simple answers so maybe that is why people seemed confused.

One solution is to generate a random number between [0,n] where n is the number of items in the current set, and instead of just removing it, you remove a range of items around that point.

Solution two is a bit more complicated but has the property of preserving set order + location such that the resulting set is just a spliced section of the original set, wheras the first solution's resulting set could be made of up multiple sections of the original set. The method here is as described initially in my post, but you also apply the random offset during each turn, not just once at the beginning.